# Modifying an already existing file gets me an error

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to modify an already existing file using openpyxl and python. I'm reading values from the file then doing a little programm and re-writing in the next column new values from the python programm.

My excel file is an xlsm file with macros working in it.

It looks like this in python :

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook 

filepath = 'filepath.xlsm'
df = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name="Sheet")
wb = load_workbook(filepath)

worksheet = wb['ER']

id = 10000000
j = 2

for row in df.iterrows():
    values = (row[1]['Column1']).split(", ")
    length = len(values)
    for i in range(length):
        values[i] = "ABC" + str(id) + "TEST"
        id = id + 1
    final_values = str(values).replace("['", "").replace("'","").replace("]","")
    worksheet.cell(row=j,column=2).value = final_values
    j = j + 1 

wb.save(filepath)
```

The programm i am having is when i open the file again. I get the following error :

> Excel Cannot Open the File Because The File Format or File Extension Is Not Valid

What do i need to change to be able to open the file correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding, `keep_vba=True`

`wb = load_workbook('filepath.xlsm', keep_vba=True)`

`xlsm` is an extension that indicates that a file contains macros. This could be a reason for your problem.

Comment: This is my bad. It is already a string. I just forget to copy it when writing my question. And even with a string i get an error

Comment: check out the last part about the file extension and `keep_vba` argument

Comment: keep_vba was the key ! thank you!